# Sublime Text 3: Build output displayed when finished

Tags: python, output, sublimetext3, build-system

Having an odd issue with Sublime Text 3.

I am able to use the Python build system to run my program and can see the output when the program finishes. My complaint is that the output is only visible once execution has finished, and with long executing programs I want to see the output to ensure they don't break mid-execution.

Does anyone know how to configure the build-panel to display the build output as it is generated?

Comment: Does anything stop you from using PyCharm or running the code in the terminal?

Comment: I've never heard of PyCharm, I'll look into that. But as far as the terminal goes I am trying to transition from using VIM & terminal to develop/execute the program and switch to sublime text due to the size of the codebase.

Comment: Build output not appearing for a long time or after the task ends is a symptom of your task not flushing `stdout` frequently enough, which stops Sublime from being able to see the output. Note that the underlying library changes how it buffers if it thinks your program is interactive, so it may behave the way you want when executed from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Tools -->Build system-->New build system -- copy and paste the below code and change the path to your python.exe

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\python\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"quiet": true
```

}

Then save as Python37.sublime-build

Hope this will help